# How to remove default chrome from a WPF ToggleButton

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

I have a `ToggleButton` defined like:

```
<ToggleButton Name="tbPinned"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,-5" Height="30" Width="30" IsChecked="True" Checked="tbPinned_Checked" Unchecked="tbPinned_Unchecked" >
            <Image Source="/some_image.png" Stretch="Fill" />
         </ToggleButton>
```

However, I just want the button to be an image, *not* an image on a button.  If I was using a normal `Button` I would just do something like `Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}"` in the opening `ToggleButton` tag.  But this does not work.

How can I mimic the whole `NoChromeButton` thing in a `ToggleButton`?

EDIT:  Editted to include how I do it with regular `Button`s:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Height="17" Margin="0,0,30,0" Name="btnMinimize" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Click="btnMinimize_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="27" Padding="0" Visibility="Visible">
            <Image Source="/some_image.png" Stretch="None"  />
        </Button>
```

Comment: Create your own custom control by deriving from ToggleButon.

Comment: No, he can use a style.  @kmarks2, can you post your `NoChromeButton` style?  You should be able to create a `ToggleButton` style that is very similar, but you can't just apply the `Button` style because `ToggleButton` does not derive from `Button`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan That's what I am trying to do in essence.  Probably some markup in a `Style`, but I'm unsure of _what_ has to change to mimic the `NoChromeButton` styling.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I've just put an edit in to show how I do this with regular buttons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just copy/paste this into new WPF project.

```
   <Window x:Class="SOChromeButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Chromeless" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0" Width="54" Height="54">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource Chromeless}" Name="tbPinned"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"  IsChecked="True" >
            <Image Source="C:\Temp\info.png"></Image>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid> </Window>
```

Comment: Excellent, it works great.  Chrome is gone.  Now, as per my original snippet, I set an image and its source within the ToggleButton.  Now that image no longer displays.  Do I need to move my ToggleButton Image into the ContentPresent of the Style?  Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer. Try this. Got it running in front of me and I can see the image.

Comment: Thanks.  Marked as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
<ToggleButton Name="tbPinned"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,-5" Height="30" Width="30" IsChecked="True" Checked="tbPinned_Checked" Unchecked="tbPinned_Unchecked" 
BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
            <Image Source="/some_image.png" Stretch="Fill" />
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything.  Possibly because `ToggleButton` derives from `CheckBox`.